# When publishing a VS2012 project, how do I build a second project before publishing the primary one?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution that has a second dependent project that contains our Telerik reports. The main project is published to our intranet server via a network path (//servername/folder) and includes a reference to the second project. The first time I tried to publish the project, I was told the report project's DLL was missing. Once I compiled the project as "Release", it published properly. So now I manually compile the report project before publishing the main project.

I am sure VS can do this all for me, but I can't figure out how to set it up, nor can I find any documentation explaining how to do this. Can anyone send me in the right direction?

Comment: I don't think deployment has anything to do with this.  Dependencies are supposed to build before the referencing project gets built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are they part of the same solution? Did you reference the other project using the "Solution" tab of Add Reference or by using Browse?

If they're part of the same solution, right click the solution and go to Properties -- not completely sure but I'd imagine setting up "Common Properties-->Project Dependencies" would affect build order.

Comment: They are in the same solution and I did use the solution tab to add to the reference. The project dependencies appear to be set up correctly.

Comment: Under the Solution's right click menu is also "Project Build Order"  -- this is read-only and is based on the project dependencies, but should tell if you if that's the issue